# Upper bound on $f(x)= \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor!}{\lfloor x+h\rfloor!} 2^{\lfloor x+h\rfloor!-\lfloor x\rfloor!}$

Tags: calculus, factorial, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am trying to show that the following function is bounded:
\begin{align}
f(x)= \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor!}{\lfloor x+h\rfloor!} 2^{\lfloor x+h\rfloor!-\lfloor x\rfloor!}
\end{align}
for some $h>0$ and $x \ge 0$.

I did a few simulations and looks like it is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is never bounded.  For instance, if $h=1$, then whenever $x$ is an integer we have $$f(x)=\frac{x!}{(x+1)!}2^{(x+1)!-x!}=\frac{2^{x\cdot x!}}{x+1}$$ which grows very very fast.  In general, $f(x)$ will have the form $\frac{y!}{(y+n)!}2^{(y+n)!-y!}$ where $y=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $n$ can be either $\lfloor h\rfloor$ or $\lceil h\rceil$ (depending on the fractional part of $x$).  As long as $n>0$, this expression grows very fast: $\frac{y!}{(y+n)!}=\frac{1}{(y+1)(y+2)\dots(y+n)}$ is roughly $\frac{1}{y^n}$ when $y$ is very large while $2^{(y+n)!-y!}>2^{y!}$ grows much faster than $y^n$.

(I am rather baffled by your "simulations" that found $f(x)$ was bounded.  Unless you were choosing values of $x$ such that $\lfloor x\rfloor=\lfloor x+h\rfloor$ and so $f(x)=1$, it should be really obvious from any examples that $f(x)$ is growing very fast.)

Comment: What if $h$ is not equal to $1$? Is it still bounded?

Comment: It is unbounded regardless of what $h$ is.  I addressed that in the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**By contradiction:**

Let $0<h<1$ be the searched constant. Then let $x:=n-\dfrac h2$ where $n$ is an integer. For this $x$,

$$f(x)=\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}2^{n!-(n-1)!}$$ and the RHS is clearly unbounded.

---

Note that if $h\ge1$, $f(x)$ is unbounded for any $x$.